# Using PySide2 on Debian causes warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome

Tags: python, qt, debian, pyside2

I have a project to do for school, using Python. I have to make a GUI, so I chose to use Qt through PySide2.
On Windows, everything runs without problem.
But when I try to run my project on Debian, I have this issue:

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
```

I've searched a solution on the Internet but nothing worked for me.
I'm using Python3.7 and PySide2 (installed with `pip`) on Debian 10.

Comment: execute: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python your_script.py`

Comment: I had this: https://pastebin.com/RjZwwx2u

Comment: Does the Debian you use have a desktop manager or is it just a terminal? Are you using debian locally or remotely?

Comment: I'm using Debian as a VM (with Virtual Box) on my computer, and I have the default desktop manager !

Comment: I also tried on my laptop which has Lubuntu 18.04 and I had the same problem.

Comment: what is the output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so`

Comment: also try with: `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland your_script.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install libxcb-xinerama0 by running this in the Terminal:

    `sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0`

That solved the issue in my case. It was simply missing.

 Let me know!